# can I turn a spa panel box into a circuit breaker box

Tags: electrical, subpanel, shed, hot-tub

I got rid of the hot tub and have 60A spa panel.  Can I purchase guts that would make it a breaker box?

Or should I just replace it with a circuit breaker box?

I want to run power to my shed.

Is it feasible to leave the spa panel in place and run a sub panel inside the shed?

I would like to not burn down the house/shed/neighborhood.....

Thanks!

Comment: Most "spa panels" really are tiny loadcenters.  How much power does your shed need? Also, is the "spa panel" mounted on the shed, or somewhere else?

Comment: "Burn down the"... Yeah, [that can happen](http://www.cnn.com/2016/08/11/us/california-valley-fire-faulty-hot-tub/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Most spa panels have 2 spaces for auxiliary loads, often they are inside the coverage of the built-in GFCI.

However you don't want to run multiple circuits over to the shed, you are only allowed one circuit per voltage.  (One 240, one 120+240, one 120). Any further division of circuits must be in a subpanel in the shed.  Don't get too small a subpanel, go for 3x what you think you need.

The subpanel can be of any current rating >= the supply, e.g. a 30A breaker can feed #10 wire to a 125A subpanel. It needs to have its own "main" breaker but it can be of any size >= supply rating, since it is only a shutoff switch.  This main breaker must bolt down, you can't just backfeed a breaker that only clips in.

If you use rigid conduit, the stuff is hella expensive, but only needs to be buried 6” instead of 12-24”.

Answer (score 0):

Run a conduit from the bottom of the spa panel over to the shed.  Install a small breaker panel in the shed.  Feed that with some #6 copper or aluminum, four wire.

Comment: #4 aluminum if you want full 60A out of it.  Aluminum is great for this.